# Translate django variable with html template value

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am trying to translate like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-7 section">
   {{ template |safe }}
</div>
```

template = `<div class="row">
                <div class="calc-head">{% trans "Calculations" %}</div>
            </div>`

But the {% trans "Calculations" %} is not working for me. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using template as a variable? Did you add it to the page as a string context object?
Save your template as an html file, remember to

```
{% load i18n %}
```

on top of the file and then put your code (with html content) inside:

```
{% blocktrans %}
{# Your html markup here #}
{% endblocktrans %}
```

And then add it to the page where you need it as:

```
{% include 'folder/name.html' %}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i have saved template in database which i need to render as variable. I am passing template as variable in context

Comment: Ok. You can still use the block format. Does that not work?